# COM port update after remove or insert new USB device

Tags: c#

I want a control element to show me changes in a running program about connected USB devices. After searching I managed to find USB devices and print them out. I also handle getting information about removing and connecting.

But now there is a problem, when I combine both parts it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
namespace usbPortAbfrage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bla();
        }

        public ArrayList GetComFriendlyNames()
        {
            ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                  new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
                  "SELECT InstanceName, PortName FROM MSSerial_PortName");

                foreach (ManagementObject port in searcher.Get())
                {
                    names.Add(port["PortName"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException)
            {
            }
            return names;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0x8004)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gerät entfernt");
                richTextBox1.Clear();
                bla();
            }

            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0x8000)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gerät angeschlossen");
                richTextBox1.Clear();
                bla();
            }
        }

        public void bla()
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();

            ArrayList test = GetComFriendlyNames();

            foreach (string name in test)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(name + "\n");
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: When I start running, it works and creat a Form, where is a 'richtextbox'. In there a standing my Comports, but if i will removing or connecting a device it clear the textbox and doesn't append new text (also the new search)

Comment: What does the event bindings against your methods look like?

Comment: Sorry Thomas I suppose that I didn't get your question right. My events are from WndProc, which takes it from windows and 0x8004 are disconnecting a device and 0x8000 are connecting device.

Comment: Hmm I've tried your code and I get most of it to work, though when I connect my USB (which is my cellphone don't have the energy to find another one) I get the WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x219 event when I connect/disconnect my device. Can it have something to do with windows already "knowing" the device?

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm

I don't have to time to do anything more than to post the code I've used to debug with but I'll check back later this evening to see if you've gotten any further.

Answer (score 0):

This is my debugging code from my tests to try and replicate the problem I can't seem to hit the event codes either. (I.E no this code won't work and it's not the answer/solution but I can't fit it into a comment, please don't vote it down!)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
    private const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;               // system detected a new device      
    private const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = 0x8003;         // about to remove, still available      
    private const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;  
    private bool appActive = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Paint a string in different styles depending on whether the 
        // application is active. 
        if (appActive)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ActiveCaption, 20, 20, 260, 50);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Application is active", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, 20, 20);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.InactiveCaption, 20, 20, 260, 50);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Application is Inactive", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Listen for operating system messages. 
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application 
            // becomes the active application or becomes inactive. 
            case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

                // The WParam value identifies what is occurring.
                appActive = (((int)m.WParam != 0));

                // Invalidate to get new text painted. 
                this.Invalidate();

                break;
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
                break;
            case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnected!");
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Link to a similar question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ea183afd-d070-4abd-8e00-a1784fdfedc5/

Comment: Hey Thomas,
thanks for your effort. I had test your code, it doesn't react on disconnecting or connecting when the programm is running. And it was one part of my issue, wich in my code work singel perfect for me(reacting on connecting and disconnecting). But if I want do more when make a MessageBox, namely call a funktion which should search devices and print it out, it doesen't work. I have test my code on another mashine and i got an exception: HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL. I will see perhaps it will be light in a dark tunnel.

Comment: If you change the event to 0x219 it should work which is the WM_DEVICECHANGE event but this doesn't solve your problem sadly.